# bootstrap ui - typeahead onselect, custom value is not displayed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

I am trying to add autocomplete functionality using bootstrap.  when a value is selected from autocomplete list, I would like to append a ":" at the end of the selected value.  For some reason this appending is not working.
My angular html code is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" id="search_es"
                       typeahead="v for v in getNext($viewValue) | filter: type_filter"
                       typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item, $model, $label)'
                       autocomplete = "off"
                       placeholder="Type to search..."  />
                <div my-search-directive="search_radar"></div>
```

Here is the onSelect js code

```
$scope.onSelect = function($item,$model,$label) {
      $scope.query += ": ";
}
```

I could capture the value of query in another variable and can display on UI, but on the bootstrap typhead text box.

I am using angular1.4.7 
ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Just slightly modified the ui-bootstrap 0.14.3 typeahead [example plunker with your select function](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxXAcPo8nNS34Hetg3Je?p=preview), and it does what you're hoping, I think. Does it help, or is there any way you could modify it to repro your issue?

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response.  for uib-typeahead instead of using states values, can we use getLocation?  I tried to modify, but was unable to get to the right code.  something like what i had above getNext($viewValue).

Comment: I couldn't fix my code and couldn't break plunker although i have the same exact values on onSelect.  it never updates the model.  Just last hope, I am loading these as well, are they interacting in anyway? bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js",bootstrap-switch-3.3.2/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js",angular-bootstrap-switch.min.js",ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"

Comment: I have an ng-if condition which is preventing it from appending.  i corrected it and it works now.  I want to give credit for your answer with plunker example.  How do I do that.

Comment: Oh, great! Glad you figured it out. I can post the above as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$scope.onSelect` function is working as expected in this [modified ui-bootstrap example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxXAcPo8nNS34Hetg3Je?p=preview). I gather you found the condition that was preventing the expected behavior, so well done.